# Persist and update an array of values with Spring boot / sql

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

**given a property object that may have a simple value like :

property1{id: 1, value: 'simplevalue'}.

persist and update those object in sql database is quite simple, where property value is string type.

The new need is to implement properties that may take an array of values like:

property2{id:1, value:['value1', 'value2']}

where the persist in the database is done as below:

row1: property_id: 1, value: 'value1'

row2: property_id: 1, value: 'value2'

i m looking for the best practices to make the update of those kind of properties.
like if a user update the property and send :

property2{id:1, value:['value1', 'value3']} OR

property2{id:1, value:['value1', 'value2','value3']} OR

property2{id:1, value:['value3','value4']}

What is the best best way to do the persistence.

PS: i want to keep the entity like that of string type values not array ones.
first solution that come to mind is detect changes and delete all old values and replace them by new one, or maybe split the function and detect which values are deleted and which one are added ...
What do you think?**

Comment: There are multiple different solutions that could be done here. It is hard to come up with a best practice without knowing a lot more about the use case.

Comment: my use case is like that :
I have a table DocumentProperty , which contain properties related to document like below :
Id(Long) - value(String) - propertyId(Long) - documentId(Long)

so when user update values of properties , it was.simple when each property has a simple value.
now we have properties that can have multiple values within the same document, and must be duplicated in the table DocumentProperty as below
{id:1, value:'value1', propertyId: 2, documentId: 101}
{id: 2, value: 'value2', propretyId: 2, documentId: 101}
and of course we still have the old simple values properties